# Does a Rails helper exist for "one, two, and three"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry for such a trivial question, but I'd feel silly building this if it already existed.

I have a vague memory of there being a Rails helper that could turn `['one', 'two', 'three']` into "one, two, and three", but I could be totally making things up. And I can't quite figure out where in the API to look since it's not in the TextHelper module, nor can I figure out what to search for.

Does this method exist, or am I just imagining it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to_sentence is the helper

Comment: And I just found it, too! Thanks :)